# select2 multiselect dropdown scrolling issue

Tags: jquery-select2

I Use multi-select search dropdown by using select2 plugins js.The PLugin is working properly. Is there any solution that supposes that I have following drop-down option:
[image]

I want whatever option I selected then after that when I am going to select second option the dropdown option started from the last selected item:

[image]

Comment: You can use the [`select2:open and select2:select`](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) events and use `lastSelectedItem.scrollIntoView()`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Could you guide me where will I add this event.

Comment: After the initialization of the select2 dropdown (`$('yourNode').select2();`) set `$('yourNode').on('select2:open', (e) => { console.log(e); }).on('select2:select', (e) => { console.log(e); });` thats all i can tell without a code example from you. You can edit your question to provide some sample data with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).